# Belly is becoming larger even though I am on diet

Tags: diet, body-fat, bellyfat

I've been on a diet since last month. I have decreased my food intake, and noticably my weight has lost a couple of pounds(5 lbs), my arms,legs have become more slender but I have been curious that my belly size seems to be the same or is becoming larger. I haven't measured it yet so I do not have a clue as to why it is like that. Recently I have been taking on whey protein shakes and have gone to the gym at least 3 times last week. I am wondering if this is the effect of me drinking protein shakes?

Also I sit for an almost unbelievable 9- 10 hours a day(work and driving home). I try to use the stairs whenever I go to the restroom, and when I go out for lunch I try to walk around 1 - 2 blocks away from the office but I am quite worried that I am still feeling "heavy".

What should I do to decrease my belly size? Apparently some muscles have already been showing my arms and I am quite happy with them, it's just that my belly has become a lot bigger. I've stopped drinking beer since last month, plus I rarely drink beer before(1-2 bottles every month). I am however used to eat salty foods, mostly peanuts. I try my best to drink water but is it ok to go past 3 litres a day?

I am 23 years old, 145 lbs, and 5'6 in height. I do full body workouts (1 day for chest, 1 day for back, 1 day for shoulders, on all three days with gym I also do abs and legs)

Answer (score 0):

Your belly can consist of three things:

- Internal belly fat, this will be fat behind your abs, around your organs, very unhealthy.
- External belly fat, how thick are the folds on and around your belly? The fat you can pinch is under your skin and thus external.
- Gas, does your belly vary a lot? Try eating less gas producing food (vegetables, mainly) and see if it makes a difference.

If it's the second, you need to eat less or exercise more to reduce your weight. If it's the second, you might need to consider some more cardio, there is some evidence that you need exercise and not just negative calories to reduce internal fat[1].

[1] http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17637702

Answer (score 0):

If you have lost 5 pounds and you have worked out, your belly has most likely not become bigger. I will wager it is in your head.

Do measurements of yourself. You can't judge small differences by looking in the mirror.

Keep up eating clean and dieting.